# Insertar registro en Mysql con Ajax y Jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Hola necesito ayuda, estoy recogiendo los valores de input tipo "text"
> de una table dinámica a medida que se agregan las filas con los botones. En el HTML se observa que cada variable tiene un incremental. El
> problema es que no sé como obtener la ruta de los input de tipo "file"
> e incrustarlo en el Ajax con la estructura ya implementada.

```
 <table class="table" id="tablaBomba1" name="tablaBomba1">
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">Tipo Bomba</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Marca</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Fluido</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Temperatura</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Caudal</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Presión</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Voltaje</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Potencia</th>
                                <th scope="col">Tipo Succión</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Diámetro succión</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Diámetro descarga</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Diámetro pozo</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Material de carcaza</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Material de impeller</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Aplicación</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Foto placa</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    
                            
                                  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="tipoBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="tipoBomba0" ></td>
                                  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="marcaBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="marcaBomba0"></td>
                                  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="fluidoBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="fluidoBomba0"></td>
                  
                                  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="temperaturaBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="temperaturaBomba0"></td>
                                  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="caudalBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="caudalBomba0"></td>
                                  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="presionBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="presionBomba0"></td>
                                  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="voltajeBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="voltajeBomba0"></td>
                                          <td><input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="potenciaBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="potenciaBomba0"></td>
                                  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="tiposuccionBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="tiposuccionBomba0"></td>
                                  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="diametrosuccionBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="diametrosuccionBomba0"></td>
                                  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="diametrodescargaBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="diametrodescargaBomba0"></td>
                                  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="diametropozoBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="diametropozoBomba0"></td>
                                  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="materialBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="materialBomba0"></td>
                                  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="impellerBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="impellerBomba0"></td>
                                  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="aplicacionBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="aplicacionBomba0"></td>
                                  <td><input type="file" placeholder="Ingrese......" name="fotoBomba0" class="cajaNombre2" id="fotoBomba0"></td>
    
                                </tr>
                               
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <input type="button" name="agregar" class="agregarFilas" value="Agregar otro requerimiento" onclick="add()">
                            <input type="button" name="agregar" class="agregarFilas" value="Borrar requerimiento" onclick="borrarFila()">
         


    function guardar(){
                            var result = [];
                            var allValues = {};
```

> Aquí selecciono la tabla y recorro los input

$("#tablaBomba1 tbody tr").each(function() {

> Aquí recorro los input tipo text, pero quiero hacer lo mismo para los input de tipo file como se ve en la imagen, todas esas rutas se debe almacenar en la variable allValues.

```
                        $(this).find("input").each(function(index) {
```

> Aquí cómo podría decir que me recorra también los input de tipo file pero extraer de cada uno la ruta y guardarla en la variable allValues.

```
                             const fieldName = $(this).attr("name");
                             allValues[fieldName] = $(this).val();


                        });
                        result.push(allValues);
                       
                       
                    });
```

> Una vez recorrido lo incrusto, pero es ahí donde entra mi duda, siguiendo con esta estructura como haría con los input tipo "file"

```
      var parametros = 
                    {
                      "guardar": "1",    
                      "doc": JSON.stringify(allValues),
                      "docMotor": JSON.stringify(allValuesMotor),
                      "docMotorreductor": JSON.stringify(allValuesMotorreductor),
                      "docSci": JSON.stringify(allValuesSci),
                      "docTanque": JSON.stringify(allValuesTanque),
                      "docRespuesto": JSON.stringify(allValuesRespuesto),
                      "docBlower": JSON.stringify(allValuesBlower),
                      "filasBomba": nFilas,
                      "filasMotor": nFilasMotor,
                      "filasMotorreductor": nFilasMotorreductor,
                      "filasSci": nFilasSci,
                      "filasTanque": nFilasTanque,
                      "filasRespuesto": nFilasRespuesto,
                      "filasBlower": nFilasBlower,
                      "correoAsesor":correoAsesor,
                      "nombreCliente":nombreCliente,
                      "numeroCliente":numeroCliente,
                      "descuentoEstimado":descuentoEstimado,
                      "tipoCotizacion":tipoCotizacion
    
                    };
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                      data:  parametros,
                      url:   'codigo_php.php',
                      dataType: 'json',
                      type:  'post',
                      beforeSend: function() 
                      {alert("enviando");}, 
                      error: function()
                      {alert("Error");},
                      complete: function() 
                      {alert("¡Listo!");},
                      success:  function (doc) 
                      {
                         
                          alert(doc);
                      }
                    }) 
                    
                   
            }
```

> Aquí recorro los input pero no se como diferenciar los input de tipo
> "file" y colocarlos en el apartado parametros.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar jquery y simplificar muchísimo lo que quieres de este modo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Escuchamos el evento 'change' del input donde cargamos el archivo
  $(document).on('change', 'input[type=file]', function(e) {
    // Obtenemos la ruta temporal mediante el evento
    var TmpPath = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    // Mostramos la ruta temporal
    $('span').html(TmpPath);
    $('img').attr('src', TmpPath);
  });

});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="upload"><br /><br />
<span></span><br /><br />
<img width="200" alt="Imagen" />
```

Créditos a: [autor de la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2995/julian-fuentes)

Comment: $("#tablaBomba1 tbody tr").each(function() {

                        $(this).find("input").each(function(index) {
                             
                             const fieldName = $(this).attr("name");
                             allValues[fieldName] = $(this).val();
                        });
                        result.push(allValues);
                       
                       
                    });   //Aquí recorro los input de tipo text, pero ahí mismo quería saber como podría hacerlo para los input de tipo file y guardarlo en la variable allValues